# JQwidget JQuery Conflict in Wordpress Admin Area

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jqwidget

I am using JQWidgets 3.8.0 within a custom Wordpress (v. 4.2.2) plugin, namely the jqxDataTable feature. Within my plugin I have the following function:

```
  public static function cp_libstaff_load_javascript(){
 ?>
    <script>
       jQuery(document).ready(function () {            
          jQuery("#emu_libstaff_staff_table").jqxDataTable(
          {
            altRows: true,
            sortable: true,
            editable: true,
            selectionMode: 'singleRow',
            columns: [
              { text: 'First Name', dataField: 'First Name', width: 200 },
              { text: 'Last Name', dataField: 'Last Name', width: 200 },
              { text: 'Product', dataField: 'Product', width: 250 },
              { text: 'Unit Price', dataField: 'Price', width: 100, align: 'right', cellsAlign: 'right', cellsFormat: 'c2' },
              { text: 'Quantity', dataField: 'Quantity', width: 100, align: 'right', cellsAlign: 'right', cellsFormat: 'n' }
            ]
        });
      });
    </script>
< ?php
 }

add_action( 'admin_footer', array( 'Libstaff_Admin','cp_libstaff_load_javascript') );
```

This function essentially breaks the pulldown menus in the Wordpress admin area. For example, on the widgets admin page, the active sidebar menus will not expand unless I comment out

```
jQuery("#emu_libstaff_staff_table").jqxDataTable
```

I know JQWidgets is supposed to be compatible with Wordpress so any ideas where the conflict is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding this script on every admin page, I targeted JUST the page of my plugin on which I needed the scripts to run.

```
// load the scripts on only the plugin page titled "library-staff" 
if (isset($_GET['page']) && ($_GET['page'] == 'library-staff')){ 
        add_action( 'admin_footer', array( 'Libstaff_Admin','cp_libstaff_load_javascript') );
}
```

When the script is run on just this page, there are no JS conflicts.